# Golang redis v9 sdk giving ??? in Hash

Tags: spring, go, redis

We have a set up whereBy redis Hash is being written to AWS redis by Spring Redis template.
Now I am trying to read the same Hash in Golang using
github.com/redis/go-redis/v9 v9.3.1

This is my code!

```
val, err := redisClient.HGet(ctx, "user_chats", userId).Result()
    switch {
    case err == redis.Nil:
        log.Println("key does not exist")
    case err != nil:
        log.Fatal("Get failed", err)
    case val == "":
        fmt.Println("value is empty")
    }
    result, err := redisClient.HGetAll(ctx, "user_chats").Result()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error getting all chat ids for user", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Result is", result)
    s := result[userId]
    return s
}
```

When I print the entireHash using HgetAll I see some weird chars printed in front of it.

```
Result is map[user:100:hahaah ��tu168473538491428454250:��srjava.util.ArrayListx����a�Isizexpwtpc-85465830822572tpc-94681574924616tpc-1396801104467750tpc-962866567187043t gp12973943794tgp816559870050427tgp875663326163364x]
```

Check the **??** .
Is the issue with Spring Redis Template, which is writing data to this hash or the issue is with Golang redis driver,which is responsible for reading it?

Comment: This is being written by RedisTemplate and is perfectly correct.  If you want to write something with Java/Spring and read it with Go, then you'll have to serialize the values properly on the java side to what you expect to read on the Go side.  Look at custom Serializer/DeSerializer.  The serializers provided assume that you'll be reading with Java, so you'll probably need to create your own by implementing RedisSerializer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yes we  are fixing this as we need to use StringSerializer in redis template.